# How to use UITextField exclusively for appearance

Tags: ios, uitextfield

[image: Screen]

Hello. I am using UITextField as a backdrop for some UILabels. It might not be the most practical way of using a backdrop but I'm using it anyway because it looks nice.

**Question:** is it possible to make the UITextField non-interact able? I don't want the keyboard popping up when clicking it, I just want it there for display purposes.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not set the label's background color and give it rounded corners? Or add the label to a plain `UIView` with the proper color and rounded corners. Using a text field is really silly for this.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thanks rmaddy....

Answer (score 1):

Look into the "User Interaction Enabled" check box in Interface builder, or set the userInterfaceEnabled property in code for your text field.